# Restart Application Server ADministration Service Timer job? Flush all Timer jobs?

Tags: search, timer-jobs

On two of my Servers, the Application Server Time Job says Failed, but I can't figure out why.  I'm looking in the logs and can't figure out why. Does anybody know where I can find procedures to flush all timer jobs?

Comment: does my answer help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try resetting the time jobs and see if if they started successfully. Also make sure that if the account which is used to run the timer job has enough access. Here are commands to reset timer jobs: Go to cmd and type following

For 2007:

```
net stop "Windows SharePoint Services Timer"

net start "Windows SharePoint Services Timer"
```

For 2010:

```
net stop  "SharePoint 2010 Timer"
net start "SharePoint 2010 Timer"
```

Comment: Is that the correct name? getting not found. Also, I've rebooted so not sure if that will help. Thanks.

Comment: Go to run->cmd -> run the above commands there

Comment: I updated for both 2007 and 2010